# Are Parts of The Mandalorian S03E06 Referencing The Wizard of Oz?

Tags: reference, the-mandalorian, the-wizard-of-oz

Episode 3.06 (*A Gun For Hire*) of the *Star Wars* TV series, *The Mandalorian* is chucked full of references and callbacks, mostly to previous *Star Wars* content & *The Mandalorian* itself, but there were other aspects of the episode reminded me very much of *The Wizard of Oz*.

- The greenery color schemes of both interior and exterior locations are in line with "Emerald City".
- The dignitaries/nobles/staff reminiscent of the hierarchy of Emerald City citizens.
- Captain Bombardier's aesthetic/hair has "curled" flourishes, like that of members of The Lollipop Guild (and some aspects of the characters or characterization felt very "pop" and/or like, *'horses of the different colors'* with unique novelties).
- Grogu behaved/treated like more of a "pet" similar to Toto, Dorothy's dog companion.
- The Commissioner felt very much like The Wizard himself :aka The Man Behind the Curtain (and there could still be some other kind of potential fallout from the events, making him more of a fraud).

So my question is, *were these things an intentional reference to *The Wizard of Oz?** I'm looking for a confirmation from EPs, director, writers, or cast members.

I would also be interested in any additional meaning for including this reference within this episode/season, but do realize, we may not know until the season is over.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the entire Mandalorian series can be compared to *The Wizard of Oz*. Not because of any references, but because most of the story is built on Din meeting different characters who are missing something and helping them find that something.